# Is Database used in Android apps?

Tags: android, database, kotlin

Learn about use Database in Android app.

I want learn about how to connect SQL Database to Android app.
And it's like YouTube and some more database used apps.

Please help me tell about Use Database in Android app.

Thanks all

Comment: what do you mean by "Please upvote " ?

Comment: Meaning voting questions

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [android sqlite database](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_sqlite_database.htm)

and for more information [SQLiteDatabase](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase) ,

use this code for connect to DB

```
public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    private static String DB_NAME = "DataBase.sqlite";
    private static String DB_PATH = "";
    private static final int DB_VERSION = 63;

    private SQLiteDatabase mDataBase;
    private final Context mContext;
    private boolean mNeedUpdate = false;


    public DBHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DB_NAME, null, DB_VERSION);
        this.mContext = context;

        DB_PATH = mContext.getApplicationInfo().dataDir + "/databases/";

        boolean dbexist = checkDataBase();
        if (dbexist)
        {
            openDataBase();
        }
        else
        {
            createDataBase();
        }
    }

    private void createDataBase()
    {
        boolean dbexist = checkDataBase();
        if (!dbexist)
        {
            this.getReadableDatabase();
            this.close();
            try
            {
                copyDataBase();
            }
            catch (IOException e)
            {
                e.printStackTrace();
              
            }
        }
    }

    private boolean checkDataBase()
    {
        boolean checkdb = false;
        try
        {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
            File dbfile = new File(myPath);
            checkdb = dbfile.exists();
        }
        catch (SQLiteException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
         
        }
        return checkdb;
    }

    private void copyDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        InputStream myinput = mContext.getAssets().open("G2DcfxJZdu/" + DB_NAME);
        OutputStream myoutput = new FileOutputStream(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        int length;
        while ((length = myinput.read(buffer)) > 0)
        {
            myoutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
        }
        myoutput.flush();
        myoutput.close();
        myinput.close();
    }

    private void openDataBase() throws SQLException
    {
        String mypath = DB_PATH + DB_NAME;
        mDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(mypath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);
    }

    @Override
    public synchronized void close()
    {
        if (mDataBase != null)
        {
            mDataBase.close();
        }
        super.close();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db)
    {

    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        if (newVersion > oldVersion)
        {
            mNeedUpdate = true;
            try
            {
                updateDataBase();
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                exception.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }


    private void updateDataBase() throws IOException
    {
        if (mNeedUpdate)
        {
            File dbFile = new File(DB_PATH + DB_NAME);
            if (dbFile.exists())
            {
                dbFile.delete();
            }

            copyDataBase();

            mNeedUpdate = false;
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onOpen(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        super.onOpen(db);
        db.disableWriteAheadLogging();
    }
```